# Javascript Object; issue accessing json array

Tags: javascript, json

I am not able to retrieve the data from my json object; the following code return undefined for `var r` in the console but the very similar code (shown below) works in JSFiddle.

```
 var currentIMGArray = new Array();

 $.ajax({
 url:"foo.php",
 type: "post",
 data: {
  action: "foo",
  parameter: foo,
 },
 dataType: "json",
 success: function (result) {
  currentIMGArray = result[3];
  console.log(currentIMGArray);
 },
 });


 $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#W").on("click", ".IMG", function() {

   console.log("currentIMGArray: "+currentIMGArray.toString());

   var IMGid = $(this).attr("id");
   console.log("IMGid: "+IMGid);

   var r = currentIMGArray.IMGid;
   console.log("r: "+r);
 })
})
```

Here is the console output:

```
[Log] {imgGallery0: "1.jpg", imgGallery1: "2.jpg"} 
[Log] currentIMGArray: [object Object]
[Log] IMGid: imgGallery0
[Log] r: undefined
```

But this code works in JSfiddle so Im confused where the difference is ?

```
var arr = {imgGallery0: "1.jpg", imgGallery1: "2.jpg"};
var b = arr.imgGallery1;
console.log(b)
```

Comment: can u try JSON.parse (currentIMGArray) and paste the result here

Comment: I think that you found the correct way, but, just one tip: instead console.log("string " + anyObject.toString()); you can use this: console.log("string ", anyObject);

Comment: thanks @MarceloRafael I'll try that next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `var r = currentIMGArray[IMGid];`
instead of `var r = currentIMGArray.IMGid;`

Since **IMGid** is a variable and can change its values, you need to access the content using an array style approach **currentIMGArray[IMGid]** this means whichever is in the **IMGid** variable **imgGallery0**, **imgGallery1** get that exact key from the **currentIMGArray** object. Imagine if you had something like **{imgGallery0: "1.jpg", imgGallery1: "2.jpg", IMGid: '3.jpg'}** how would you get the **3.jpg**?
**currentIMGArray.IMGid** in this case will return **3.jpg**

Comment: @jotyhista Since IMGid is a variable and can change its values, you need to access the content using an array style approach
currentIMGArray[IMGid]
this means whichever is in the IMGid variable imgGallery0, imgGallery1 get that exact key from the currentIMGArray object.
Imagine if you had something like
{imgGallery0: "1.jpg", imgGallery1: "2.jpg", IMGid: '3.jpg'} 
how would you get the 3.jpg?
currentIMGArray.IMGid in this case will return 3.jpg

Comment: I see. Thank you I did not know that; explains why JSfiddle worked.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
var r = currentIMGArray[IMGid];
```

when you put `var r = currentIMGArray.IMGid` you are trying to access an attribute named `IMGid` on the `currentIMGArray` object, thats why it returns `undefined`